# Why does the given list give me list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple error?

Tags: python, arrays

I don't see any tuples in here but still I get the error.
I have tried everything and still doesn't work.

```
C= 0
C1 = 5
C2 = 4
C3 = 1
original = [[1,C,2,5,2]
        [1,C,6,2,7]
        [1,C,2,4,7]
        [1,C,5,2,2]
        [2,C1,3,2,3]
        [2,C1,2,8,5]
        [2,C1,6,2,6]
        [2,C1,6,3,4]
        [2,C1,5,2,2]
        [3,C2,2,3,6]
        [3,C2,2,7,9]
        [3,C2,1,6,2]
        [4,C3,2,9,4]
        [4,C3,0,3,2]]
print(original)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\satish\Desktop\python projects\logic.py", line 6, in <module>
    [1,C,6,2,7]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Comment: put commas between the lists

Comment: You forgot to separate the sub-lists with commas.  So it's treating the next sub-list as a list index rather than a new list element.

Comment: Voting to close since the problem is due to a typo.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use commas to use a list of lists, you have a wrong syntax:

Try this below :

```
    C = 0
    C1 = 5
    C2 = 4
    C3 = 1
    original = [[1, C, 2, 5, 2],
                [1, C, 6, 2, 7],
                [1, C, 2, 4, 7],
                [1, C, 5, 2, 2],
                [2, C1, 3, 2, 3],
                [2, C1, 2, 8, 5],
                [2, C1, 6, 2, 6],
                [2, C1, 6, 3, 4],
                [2, C1, 5, 2, 2],
                [3, C2, 2, 3, 6],
                [3, C2, 2, 7, 9],
                [3, C2, 1, 6, 2],
                [4, C3, 2, 9, 4],
                [4, C3, 0, 3, 2]]
    print(original)
```